# Input type image submit form without my consense

Tags: javascript, html, image, forms, input

i've an input type image like this:

```
<input type="image" name="formimage2" width="170" height="37" src="images/tasto-registrati.png" onclick="sub()">
```

this is sub():

```
function sub(){
            var mail = document.getElementsByName('mail')[0];
            var name = document.getElementsByName('name')[0];
             if(mail.value!=""){
                bool = true;
            }else{
                mail.value="Campo obbligatorio";
                mail.style.backgroundColor="red";
                bool=false;
            }
            if(name.value!=""){
                bool = true;
            }else{
                name.value="Campo obbligatorio";
                name.style.backgroundColor="red";
                bool=false;
            }
if(bool){
   document.form[0].submit();
}
```

but form submit everytime! how can i tell to form to submit only in that case?
i try:

```
if(bool){
...
}else{
   return false
}
```

but nothing! can you help me??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

`onclick="return sub()"`

I believe your form will not get submitted when it is `FALSE`...

Good Luck!!!

**Update 1:**

always use `return false` or `return true` in main function itself...

**javascript part**

```
function checkMe() {

if (Name is incorrect) {
alert(Name is incorrect);
return false;
}


if (Number is incorrect) {
alert(Number is incorrect);
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

**html part**

```
<input type=submit onClick="return checkMe()">
```

Comment: I don't get you... what you are doing so that it is not working for second time??

Comment: :) understood! i made mistake.. if fields are empty, i fill it with text "field required", so when i check if field is empty the second time it see that is not empty cause there is text "field required" :P

Comment: they way you are doing is checking everything... in my case if "Name is incorrect" it will not check further...

Comment: sorry if i didn't accept before but i must w8 for some minutes before accept it :) thanks you very much!

Comment: Great. worked great for me. Really like this question and answer. I was using safari 8.0.4 at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `onsubmit="return sub()"` for `form` tag.

Also you should `return bool;` Form will be submitted if `bool` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="image" name="formimage2" width="170" height="37" src="images/tasto-registrati.png" onclick="sub(event)">

function sub(e){

  ...
  ...
  if(!bool){
     e.preventDefault();
  }else{
     ......
  }


}
```